# django registration accounts cannot find url to register

Tags: python, django, url, heroku

I've been trying for hours to find the solution to this problem:

```
admin/
accounts/ ^activate/complete/$ [name='registration_activation_complete']
accounts/ ^activate/resend/$ [name='registration_resend_activation']
accounts/ ^activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$ [name='registration_activate']
accounts/ ^register/complete/$ [name='registration_complete']
accounts/ ^register/closed/$ [name='registration_disallowed']
accounts/ ^register/$ [name='registration_register']
accounts/ ^login/$ [name='auth_login']
accounts/ ^logout/$ [name='auth_logout']
accounts/ ^password/change/$ [name='auth_password_change']
accounts/ ^password/change/done/$ [name='auth_password_change_done']
accounts/ ^password/reset/$ [name='auth_password_reset']
accounts/ ^password/reset/complete/$ [name='auth_password_reset_complete']
accounts/ ^password/reset/done/$ [name='auth_password_reset_done']
accounts/ ^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$ [name='auth_password_reset_confirm']
```

Django3 has registration-redux installed and the registration model is trying really hard to find the logout url

```
..herokuapp.com/accounts/logout
```

But its seemed to go through the urls in order above and not matching on accounts/logout, and including a space in the account views configured by registration-redux.

Annoying because I've installed registration in my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf import settings
from contacts.views import profile
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, reverse, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include(site_urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    path('accounts/profile', profile, name='profile'),
    path('', include('contacts.urls')),
]
```

As well as migrating to use the path style urls as opposed to urls. Any help here appreciated as I don't understand why it cant match the account/logout url.

Comment: You ever tried `accounts/logout/`? Like adding a frontslash at the very end of your URL?

Comment: I have now... Seems to have done the trick. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

My template needed:

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="rs-navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li><a href="#">Logged in as {{ request.user }}</a></li>
                <li><a href="/accounts/logout/"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"> </i> Logout</a></li>
            {% else %}
                <li><a href="/accounts/login/">Login</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </div>
```

A forward slash at the end.